# Error "An argument named ... is not expected here" for terraform resource

Tags: terraform, resources, datadog

I'm trying to replicate the nested use of for_each at https://blog.boltops.com/2020/10/06/terraform-hcl-nested-loops/, and am getting an error `An argument named "name" is not expected here.` right after the first for_each.  So I've narrowed it down to the following code:

```
 # Datadog Performance Dashboard

  locals {
      dashboard_title = "Title here"
      hosts = toset( [ "host1", "host2"] )
      params = {
          "CPU" = [
              {
              title = "System Load - 1 min avg"
              dd_param = "avg:system.load.norm.1"
              }
          ]
          "RAM" = [
              {
              title = "Memory Commit limit"
              dd_param = "system.mem.commit_limit"
              }
          ]
      }
  }


  resource "datadog_dashboard" "ordered_dashboard" {
 #   for_each = local.params
      #name = each.key
      name          = "asdadas"

      title         = local.dashboard_title
      description   = "Created using the Datadog provider in Terraform"
      layout_type   = "ordered"
      is_read_only  = true

  }
```

Since `name = each.key` doesn't work (i.e. gives the same error `An argument named name is not expected here`, one can see I tried commenting out the for_each, the each.key assignment and the rest of the nested loop, and it's still complaining about the variable.

It would make sense that maybe I need to declare it before using it, but I find the code in the link I mentioned earlier doesn't do it.  Neither does https://www.terraform.io/language/resources/syntax nor https://www.terraform.io/language/expressions/dynamic-blocks, both from Hashicorps' Terraform documentation site.

This is the version of terraform I'm using:

```
$ terraform -v
Terraform v1.1.3
on darwin_amd64
+ provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws v3.73.0
```

Anyone have thoughts on what I'm missing here?  Why is terraform complaining on the variable assignment?

Comment: Try changing your `"CPU"` and `"RAM"` keys from from quoted strings to unquoted identifiers like e.g. `cpu` and `ram` and see what happens

Comment: According to the documentation, there is indeed no argument `name` for the resource: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/DataDog/datadog/latest/docs/resources/dashboard. What are you trying to do with the `name` argument? I would have guessed `title`, except you already provided a value for that argument.

Comment: 1. When I remove the quotes from 'CPU' and 'RAM' and run terraform apply, I get the same error.   Also, I was able to get this to run by leaving out the variable declaration, but as I want to use the information in that variable, it's not a viable workaround.

Comment: 2. @MattSchuchard - I'm trying access the information at that level in the data structure so that as I iterate through it in creating the dashboard, I can group them appropriately.    That said, I see what you're saying about the name not being an argument per the datadog documentation, but they why would the for_each give the same error?  In other words, I'd have thought the lines I commented out would be for the local.params local, not anything that datadog set.

Comment: Regardless of whether you include the `for_each` meta-argument or not, there is no `name` argument for that resource, so it is unrelated. I honestly am unsure what you are trying to do here with that argument. Maybe it would be best to start over with the resource documentation at https://registry.terraform.io/providers/DataDog/datadog/latest/docs/resources/dashboard. Then if you want to iterate continue with `for_each` documentation: https://www.terraform.io/language/meta-arguments/for_each. Ignore any blog articles and focus on the actual documentation and see how that goes.

Comment: After you have that working, continue with dynamic blocks: https://www.terraform.io/language/meta-arguments/for_each. If you now need nested iteration, you can look at: https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/flatten#flattening-nested-structures-for-for_each.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that the resource `datadog_dashboard` doesn't have an argument named `name`, so it gives such an error.

For more information take a look carefully to:
https://registry.terraform.io/providers/DataDog/datadog/latest/docs/resources/dashboard